# static method in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have class like below

```
template<class T>
class Student
{
 public:
  static Student& Instance();
}

template<class T>
Student<T>& Student<T>::Instance()
{
 ...
 return student;
}
```

It returns LNK2001 error. Can I use this way?

Comment: You're not providing all your relevant code.  How can the compiler know what `student` is from the code above?  (Your link error is probably because you declare but don't define student)

Comment: Yes, please provide some sample code that at least compiles (semicolons in the proper places, etc.), then we can look at the linker error.

Comment: Is this the real code? Does it give *linker* error? I cannot. However, it can give *compilation* error, as the class definition doesn't end with a semicolon `;`.

Comment: To all commentators above: "LNK2001 error" is enough to get what's happens there. Use google to find error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ambiguous, so I try to guess your problem. If you declared class Student in Student.h and implement method Instance() in Student.cpp, that is your problem. Implement method Instance() in Student.h.

Answer (score 1):

Either `Student<T>::Instance` should be in header file, either you should provide specializations of `Student<>` methods in .cpp files.